# OnChange in MudBlazor RadioButtonGroup

Tags: events, radiobuttonlist, mudblazor

I am new to Blazor and MudBlazor.  I am using a  and I want to call an event when the selection changes.  The documentation show there is a **EventCallback** method but there are no syntax examples.  I have been searching a good part of the day but cannot find an example.  Can anyone please share some simple code?  I know I can bind to a variable, and I initially did that.  What I want is to call code and do some different code based on the selected value.  Seems to be easier to do in Blazor syntax vs MudBlazor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<MudRadioGroup T="string" SelectedOption="@SelectedOption" SelectedOptionChanged="OnSelectedOptionChanged">
    <MudRadio Option="@("Radio 1")" Color="Color.Primary">Primary</MudRadio>
    <MudRadio Option="@("Radio 2")" Color="Color.Secondary">Secondary</MudRadio>
    <MudRadio Option="@("Radio 3")">Default</MudRadio>
    <MudRadio Option="@("Radio 4")" Color="Color.Primary" Disabled="true">Disabled</MudRadio>
</MudRadioGroup>

@code {
    public string SelectedOption { get; set; }

    private void OnSelectedOptionChanged(string selectedOption)
    {
        SelectedOption = selectedOption;

        // call your stuff
    }
}
```

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mOQGYtGKUpgnQxqe

Comment: Hello, thank you!!!
      After looking at your example, which is what I based my test off of, I realized that I was missing the T="string".  That is why it was throwing an error.  I initially had this code @bind-SelectedOption="@SelectedOption" which does work.. but needed the event instead.

Comment: Yes the type of `SelectedOptionChanged` is `EventCallback<T>` so when you need to use it you have to also specify the `T` parameter.

Comment: I was trying the onClick event which does not fire. This worked perfectly! Many thanks!

Comment: How can I use this code block inside a for loop? I wanna render a MudRadioGroup for each an every item in a list. But SelectedOptionChanged get called multiple times even if I change only one group.

Comment: Like this: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wEGdanclIagugzhO

Comment: If I put await in OnSelectedOptionChanged Method, that will cause this method run twice, and don't change the radio selected index, did you know why?